# Why does it make sense to delta hedge a deep OTM option given the very low delta exposure?

Tags: delta-hedging

I am not sure if this is actually done in practice as I'm not a derivatives trader, but I can only think of reducing the cost of the OTM option as a reason for delta hedging a deep OTM option, which is likely to be pricey/expensive.

Appreciate the help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the participant, but generally speaking, say in the FX markets, hedge funds would buy options to get exposure to volatility, not the underlying, so they delta hedge the option. The banks desks dealing  the options don’t want exposure to the underlying either as these would be volatility desks whose expertise is vol so they would delta hedge as well. Hence there is an automatic match, and you will get better terms than if you were to hedge delta with a new counterparty or as a new trade.

The delta hedge will be updated as the option delta changes but you will have to start somewhere, though possibly many participants would have a strategy to hedge only material exposure. but then you won’t own just one option.

Comment: Does this mean then that the hedge funds and the banks generally don't want delta exposure? I would've thought hedge funds do use options to take directional bets on the underlying.

Comment: Yes hedge funds come in many flavours indeed, and there is a whole host of strategies. The volatility strategies would be delta hedging the underlying as the vol is more important

Comment: Right this makes sense. Just a few follow ups from me: are banks just trading vol now? And has this always been the case - or is vol trading just the flavour of the month currently?

Comment: It varies by bank but they would desire to be market makers, matching buyers and sellers, than taking positions. It could be chaotic because market conditions have been challenging  recently so the individual banks behaviour changes, at times drastically.

Comment: hmm interesting